# ¿Como simulo un click en x e y?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

estoy haciendo un pequeño programa que detecta colores en una imagen y al hacer click pone un punto rojo, hasta ahi todo bien excepto por la parte del click

```
 static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);
  
mouse_event(Mouse_DRH, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, 0, 0);
```

Logre hacer el click el problema es que no suelta el click lo presiona y nunca lo vuelve a soltar alguien puede hecharme la mano por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nos faltaría saber el valor de `Mouse_DRH` para ver cual es el fallo.

En cualquier caso, ese flag toma valores distintos para ejecutar el click y soltarlo. En el primer caso su valor debería ser *0x00000002*, mientras que, para soltarlo debería tomar el valor *0x00000004*.

Espero que te sirva!